# TypeScript duck typing: Require only one property

Tags: typescript, duck-typing

With the following code;

```
interface ParamTest extends Object {
  ids?: any;
  model?: any;
  params?: any;
  pageContext?: PageContext;
}

class Foo {
    public callMeWithParamsPlease(params: ParamTest): void{

    }

    public nope() {
        this.callMeWithParamsPlease("hi");
    }
}
```

I don't know what I will be supplied as a parameter. But I know that ***at least one*** of the fields must be filled up. If I use:

```
export interface ApiServiceOpts extends Object {
  ids?: any;
  model?: any;
  params?: any;
  pageContext: PageContext;
}
```

Then it's no longer compatible with string, as expected - because string doesn't have `pageContext`. However I don't know for sure if the pageContext would be supplied - but I know that at least one of the fields needs to be supplied. Is there any magical typescript syntax which allows this?

Maybe something like;

```
interface PageContext {}


export interface ParamTestId {
  ids: any;
}

export interface ParamTestModel {
  model: any;
}

export interface ParamTestParams {
  params: any;
}

export interface ParamTestPageContext {
  pageContext: PageContext;
}

class Foo {
    public callMeWithParamsPlease(params: ParamTestId & ParamTestModel & ParamTestParams & ParamTestPageContext): void {
        params.ids.a = ""; 
        params.model.b = {}
    }

    public nope() {
        this.callMeWithParamsPlease("hi")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `"it's no longer compatible with string"` - when was it ever compatible with a string, what is this "it"? No where in your code do you have a string param. Also, why would you extend `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Extending `Object` doesn't add anything, your interface is already an object. Remove that.
- Your type was compatible with `string` because a `string` is also an `Object` but you shouldn't rely on that, instead use type unions to explicitly indicate that you accept objects or strings, i.e.

  ```
  callMe(params:ParamTest|string) {
    // params may be a string now regardless of ParamTest's definition.
  }
  ```
- At this point you should use type guards to check what you actually got in the params, i.e.:

  ```
  interface ParamTest {
    ids:string[];
    paramContext:string;
  }
  class Foo {
    callMeMaybe(params:ParamTest|string) {
      if (params instanceof String) {
        // Cool it's a string.
        let x = params.charCodeAt(0);
      } else {
        let m = params.ids;
      }
    }
  }
  ```